# Expected value of a deterministic function defined on a random domain

Tags: probability, expected-value

I'm curious of how to find the expected value of the following. Suppose we have a constant function defined on,

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
             1 & if  \ \  \  0 < x< D  \\
                    0  & if  \ \ \ x> D
  \end{cases}$$

For $$D \sim Exp(2)$$

Is there anyway to compute

$$\mathbb{E}(f(x))=?$$

Comment: One typically uses calculus to solve this kind of question.

Comment: @kimchilover lol, so helpful

Comment: Is $f$ supposed to be a pdf of a random variable (in that case, you should divide by $D$) or it's just a function and the answer should be a function of $x$?

Comment: @YJT The answer should be a function. I'm not sure even how to google this kind of question? Like it is a function of a random variable, but not in the classical way.

Comment: I would "expect" the answer to be f(x) = 1 for 0 < x  < .5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x$. The random variable $Y=f(x)$ can be either $1$, with probability $\Pr(D>x)$ or $0$.
Hence, $E(f(x))=\Pr(D>x)=\exp(-2x)$